# Firebase phonenumber authentication doesn't send SMS verification code

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a web app using firebase authentication with phonenumber, but firebase doesn't send the SMS verification code to my phonumber, no errors, no warnings.

angular project.

`npm i firebase`

login.html

```html
<button (click)="loginPhoneNumber()">Login with Phone</button>

<div id="recaptcha-container" name="recaptcha-container"></div>
```

login.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const firebase = {
      apiKey: "XXzaSyCXXrywlvhKPEaxaa-XXJmPiYck0olYXX0",
      authDomain: "ooowwapp-111fb.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "ooowwapp-111fb",
      storageBucket: "ooowwapp-111fb.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "134560933011",
      appId: "1:134560933011:web:113bba1111e89742897111"
    };
    this.app = initializeApp(firebase);
    this.auth = getAuth(this.app);
  }

  async loginPhoneNumber(): Promise<User|null> {
    let phoneNumber: string = "+5511914115181";
    
    (window as any).recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      'size': 'normal',
      'callback': (response:any) => {
        console.log('response',response);
      },
      'expired-callback': () => {
        console.log('expired');
      }
    }, this.auth);
  
    const appVerifier = (window as any)?.recaptchaVerifier;
    console.log('appVerifier',appVerifier);
  
    const confirmationResult = await signInWithPhoneNumber(
      this.auth,
      phoneNumber,
      appVerifier
    );
    console.log('confirmationResult',confirmationResult);
    ...
  }
```

Logs in the Browser Inspector:
[image]

Firebase configuration:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find something? The lack of documentation is killing me!

Comment: It seems to a problem with the free tier. Wait a few hours.